# Unity3D change MeshRender form a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to replace entire Mesh or GameObject ( not instantiate or disable and enable other ), because my Mesh is different from other but the GameObject, position and script is the same, so, thats why i need to change **ONLY** the Mesh ( i guess this is the right way to do ).

So, this is the code in C#

```
public GameObject MyMainGameObject;
public GameObject[] OtherMeshMaterials;

int maxMaterials;
int arrayPos = 0;

void Start ()
{
    maxMaterials = OtherMeshMaterials.Length-1;

    Debug.Log ( "Total = "+ maxMaterials );
}

void updateMaterials()
{
    //Cycle forward
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.U)) {
        if (arrayPos == maxMaterials)
            arrayPos = 0;
        else
            arrayPos++;

        MyMainGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = OtherMeshMaterials[arrayPos].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        MyMainGameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh       = OtherMeshMaterials[arrayPos].GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        Debug.Log ( "NAME = "+ MyMainGameObject.transform.name );
    }



    //Cycle backwards
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Y)) {            
        if (arrayPos == 0)
            arrayPos = maxMaterials;
        else
            arrayPos--;

        MyMainGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material  = OtherMeshMaterials[arrayPos].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        MyMainGameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh        = OtherMeshMaterials[arrayPos].GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        Debug.Log ( "NAME = "+ MyMainGameObject.transform.name );
    }
}



void Update ()
{
    updateMaterials ();
}
```

When I change to another, the mesh is smaller than the other (but not the problem yet) and no longer changes, the name is changed, but the change of mesh happens once and never again ...

i use 4 or more **OtherMeshMaterials** to test more options but only changed once.

Thanks for help!

**EDITED**
Script go to ARCamera.
Here a image of 2 Game Objects: http://www.loverde.com.br/temp_files/Unity_MeshsToChange.png
1 - Hexa_GO > it_hex_3450 > pms_hexa5034 ( this is the Game Object i link to script )
2 - Eko_GO > it_eko_3450 > pms_eko_5034 ( this is the Game Object i link to script too )

I trying to change pms_hexa5034 to pms_ekoxxx and vice/versa. Change only one and never go back and never foward.

**EDITED**
Please, see comments on the approved answered to find what i do.
Thank you @gunnar-b to help all this days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See Edit 3 for solution]

Well, I tried your code like this:

I created an empty gameobject and attached that script to it. Then I created a cube and assigned it to "myMainGameObject". After that I created a sphere, a capsule, a cylinder and another cube and four materials (just four different colors), one added to each, the one for the cube to both cubes. I set the size of "otherMeshMaterials" to 4 and assigned the 4 additional gameobjects (0: cube, 1: sphere, 2: capsule, 3: cylinder).

With this setup the cycling works fine, forward and backward. There is no name change though (as it is not in the code right now) and of course the size changes as those objects have a different size by default.

Also, just having the four reference gameobjects just as prefabs in the folder and not instantiated in the scene works fine.

So, as far as I can tell, the problem is not related to the code itself. We need more information about the stuff around the script. How is this set up?

Edit:
Oh well, I could replicated your problem now. I didn't quite copy your script, I changed capitalization at a few points: All variable names starting with a small letter (not only the private ones, but also the public ones) and methods with a capital letter.
Changed them all to match your code again and for some reason that killed it. Even reverting it doesn't work any more.

Edit 2:
Ok, I spotted the problem: currently the reference objects are changed too so they are loosing their assigned mesh and material. If you select a reference object and watch it in the inspector you'll see "Type mismatch" during runtime and "Missing (Mesh)" not runtime.

Edit 3:
Ok, found the solution: You need to use "sharedMaterial/sharedMesh" instead of "material/mesh".

So adjust the following (for U and Y or put these two lines in a seperate method and call it):

```
myMainGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = otherMeshMaterials[arrayPos].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial;
myMainGameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh       = otherMeshMaterials[arrayPos].GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
```

Comment: The other objects (meshes) is attached to the MAIN gameobject ? like, is there one gameobject only ?

Comment: I have one empty object, that has the script on it. Then I have a cube which gets changed (assigned to "myMainGameObject"). The other four objects (one additional cube, identical to the changing one) first where in the scene too, but I made them to prefabs and removed them (assigning the prefabs to the script then). Made a change to the post, see the edit. Going to try if I can find the problem.

Comment: Yeah, i don't use caps for initial too, but to be quickly in here, i do that and dont notice! rsrsr Thanks for your help!!! I will wait for your comment if can or cant, Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, i will try now! See my edition part if it help you. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, for me that works all fine now. Here's a link with the project (ignore the other thing in there, that project is for testing stuff): http://www.file-upload.net/download-9872226/CodeTests.zip.html

Comment: Thanks for your code! It is a little bit different, but the intention is the same, i will try to improve that! Thank you very much!

Comment: i found the problem, prefab inside a prefab. Why ? Why im using image target ( prefab ) and prefab ( main object ) inside this target... when i do it in your example, nothing work... like mine... you have an ideia how to adjust this ? Thanks again

Comment: You have an empty gameobject with an prefab inside (cubeinstance) and a prefab inside that (quad)? The texture that shall change is on the quad or on the cube? Maybe provide me the project of me you modified, I think that will be the easiest way. Put a comment in the script saying what shall happen.

Comment: Here the link http://www.loverde.com.br/temp_files/CodeTestsPrefb.zip, I want to change the QUAD only, using all prefabs that you created. I just created one more to stay exactly the same format I'm using and see if the error is repeated.

Comment: Wow, this is quite weird. When I delete the quad from the scene, re-adjust the quad-prefab to have a quad-mesh for the mesh-filter again and then place the quad again as child of the cube and assign it to the variable it works. I have no idea what is going on there :D Check this out, this currently works fine for me, just adjusted the script a bit for less GetComponent calls and a collider update (don't know if you'll need that). http://www.file-upload.net/download-9914353/CodeTests2.zip.html

Comment: This code help me A LOT!!! i create a empty prefab, add mesh render and filter to load like a existent prefab, get yout C# and BOOM work! Thank you very much for your time to help!!! And helped!!! Thanks again!!!